# mysql strange situation with unix_timestamp

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

Simple question:

I have 2 Mysql servers and I run this query in both:

```
select unix_timestamp('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Results:

On server 1:

```
mysql> select unix_timestamp('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('0000-00-00 00:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                  NULL |
+---------------------------------------+
```

On server 2:

```
mysql> select unix_timestamp('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('0000-00-00 00:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I need the 0 in both cases.

Why? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume that your two servers do not run the same MySQL version.

MySQL returns `0` when you pass a timestamp to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` that is out of range.

MariaDB (the MySQL fork that is currently used by some Linux distributions as the default) returns `NULL` in the same situations.

A timestamp is out of range for UNIX time if it is before 1970-01-01 00:00:00 or after 2038-01-19 03:14:08. This is because it is stored as a 32-bit unsigned integer. 1970-01-01 00:00:00 is `0` and since it is unsigned it cannot express anything before that. On 2038-01-19 03:14:08 the integer will reach its maximum value and anything after that also cannot be expressed as a UNIX timestamp. (A solution that is already in place on some systems is to use a 64-bit integer instead, giving us several hundred thousand years extra.)

See the MySQL documentation for [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and [a MariaDB-related article about this problem](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/unix_timestamp/).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, But no, I am not using same versions... I think   the problem is the versions..

Comment: Is one of the two servers running with sql mode setting [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)? (You can post the sql mode setting of both servers. Retrieve it with `SELECT @@global.sql_mode;`.)

Answer (score 0):

Error handling

In MySQL and MariaDB before 5.3 wrong arguments to UNIX_TIMESTAMP() returned 0. Starting fromMariaDB 5.3 we return NULL for wrong arguments to UNIX_TIMESTAMP().